# Does anybody actually use FaultReasonText to localize faults from WCF services?

Tags: wcf, localization, wcf-faults

There is a localization mechanism in WCF that enables one to localize faults returned to client, via a FaultReasonText object that's a part of the fault.

The way this is done is that you pass all possible translations of the fault's message inside a collection in the FaultReasonText. This, I understand, is based on SOAP v1.2.

Does anyone actually use this mechanism? Isn't this wasteful in terms of bandwidth? Why would you send all possible translations to a client that is (probably) only interested in a specific language?

Comment: Not so wastefull as faults should not happen THAT often.... that said, I know of noone. Lets see who answers ;)

Comment: Hi TomTom. I'm actually thinking of somehow extending this to regular responses as a means to providing localized content from my server. I guess in this context the waste is more relevant.

Comment: Also wonder why the constructor of FaultException<TDetail> allows you to specify a FaultReason when the reason should be contained in the TDetail object itself one would think. Or why there are no public constants defined for standard FaultCode names and namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

[FaultReason Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultreason%28v=vs.110%29)
allows to store multiple translations if it's needed, e.g to cache possible fault descriptions in different languages.

However normally constructor [FaultReason(FaultReasonText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404988%28v=vs.110%29)) will be used to Initialize a new instance of the FaultReason class using the specified text element that describes the fault in a specific language.